# date display inline regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I have searched SO and Google for assistance with writing this inline regular expresson but could not find any help. I have tried many times now, but cannot get it working.

I have a date value that is displayed as mm/yyyy.

How do I write the regular expression to display the date as yyyy/mm?

This is just to change the display, not to validate the date.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here is the element that I want to apply the inline regex to:

```
$('#id_voluntary_finish_date').val().replace("/", '.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to transform the date format inline, dispense with the regex method and use the following:

Javascript: [.substr()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) and [.charAt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charat.asp)

Here is a working example:

```
// convert the date format from yyyy-mm to mm.yyyy
document.getElementById("id_of_element").value = ($("#id_of_element").val().substr(5,7) + $("#id_of_element").val().charAt(4) + $("#id_of_element").val().substr(0,4)).replace("-", ".");
```

if you do not need to change the date separator, simply remove the .replace("-", ".") from the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var regexp= /(\d+)\/(\d+)/;
regexp.exec(mm/yyyy);
alert(RegExp.$2 + "/" + RegExp.$1);
```

EDIT:

```
var regexp= /(\d+)\/(\d+)/;
regexp.exec($('#id_voluntary_finish_date').val());
alert(RegExp.$2 + "." + RegExp.$1);
```

Comment: how do I append the regex to an element like this: $('#id_voluntary_finish_date').val()?

Comment: Jens, thanks, but I really need the regex to be inline. I am not sure that is possible.

Comment: @user3354539 what do you mean with inline?